# make: Circular dependency dropped

Tags: assembly, makefile, yasm

I've already searched a long time on stackoverflow and other make manuals, websites but cannot find any trailing whitespace or miss usage in make functions. Can you help me solve this warning message ?

```
make: Circular main.asm.o <- main.asm dependency dropped.
```

Makefile:

```
AS:=yasm
CC:=gcc
OUTPUTDIR:=$(shell pwd)/bin
ASFLAGS:=-g dwarf2 -f elf64 -a x86
CFLAGS:=-g

SOURCES=$(wildcard *.asm)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.asm,%.o,$(SOURCES))

%.o: $(SOURCES)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUTDIR)/$(OBJECTS) $<

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o httpd $(OUTPUTDIR)/$(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm $(OUTPUTDIR)/*
    rm httpd
```

main.asm:

```
section .text
  global main
  extern exit

main:
  mov rdi, 1
    call exit
```

thanks you :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your error is this line:

```
%.o: $(SOURCES)
```

which presumably expands to something like

```
%.o: main.asm foo.asm bar.asm
```

What that means is something very approximately like

```
main.asm.o: main.asm
foo.asm.o: foo.asm
bar.asm.o: bar.asm
    ....
```

That's 'approximately' because you're mixing up the syntax here.

You're confusing an ordinary rule (`target: source`) with a wildcard rule (`%.target: %.source`).  What you probably want is

```
%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

which teaches Make how to make `.o` files from `.asm` files, combined with

```
httpd: $(SOURCES:.asm=.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o httpd $*
```

which tells Make how to combine the various `.o` files into the `httpd` executable.  The `$(SOURCES:.asm=.o)` variable reference expands to a list of `.o` files as dependencies, and Make now knows how to create those `.o` files from the corresponding `.asm` files.

Extra observations:

1. In case it's not obvious, what `$(SOURCES:.asm=.o)` does is to expand to the value of `$(SOURCES)`, but with trailing `.asm` replaced by `.o`.
2. What *I personally* would do with this Makefile is to replace the `wildcard` in the definition of `SOURCES` with an explicit list of files.  That way, you won't get unexpected results if you, for example, add a `my-temp-test.asm` file to the directory. (This comes under the heading of ‘how can I be nice to future-me?’)

Answer (score 2):

```
AS:=yasm
CC:=gcc
ASFLAGS:=-g dwarf2 -f elf64 -a x86
CFLAGS:=-g

OBJECTSDIR:=$(shell pwd)/bin
SRCDIR:=$(shell pwd)/src
SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.asm)
OBJECTS=$(shell find $(OBJECTSDIR) -name *.o)


%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJECTSDIR),$@) $<

httpd: $(SOURCES:.asm=.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o httpd $(OBJECTS)


clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTSDIR)/*
    rm -f httpd
```

Thanks to you explication Norman, I did that. It's important for me to have distinct folders, /bin and /src so that everything stay clear.

Thank you, It's working and I understand my error.

note:  if I put any object file in the Makefile folder I got weird error from make... just deleting them make it working again.

Comment: So you don't actually need any asm files other than `main.asm`?

Comment: of course not, but grep -v is the opposite result, means that I have all .asm file in $(SOURCE) except main.asm

Comment: And you don't use them.